# How do we provide custom jndi name for EJB3 in Weblogic12

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy an ejb but would like to provide custom jndi name for it. 
I created below: weblogic-ejb-jar.xml
`

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.2/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">
  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>test</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>ejb/test</jndi-name>
    <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

`
 But when I try to look up bean using this jndi name, I get   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.

Is there any configuration that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are not looking up the bean correctly. You could try the following.

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
test testInstance = (test)
initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/test");
```